# Clicking multiple play buttons and playing the corresponding songs

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

Javascript:

```
function Start1 ()
{
    var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    audie.src = ("RWY.mp3");
    audie.play();
}

function Start2 ()
{
    var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    audie.src = ("EL.mp3");
    audie.play();
```

HTML

```
<img src="images/play.png" alt="Play Button width="37" height="30" 
onclick="Start1()">
```

I'm trying to select an image and as soon as that image is clicked a song plays according to the file described in the element.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be I didn't get you problem but Why are you making separate function for each image or audio. You can do it using single function as well by just passing the source of audio file like this

```
function Start (audioFile)
{
    var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    audie.src = audioFile;
    audie.play();
}
```

Markup:

```
<img src="images/play.png" alt="Play Button width="37" height="30" onclick="Start('RWY.mp3')">

<img src="images/play.png" alt="Play Button width="37" height="30" onclick="Start('EL.mp3')">
```

Update:

```
function StartOrStop(audioFile)
  {
    var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    audie.src = audioFile;
    if(audie.paused==false)
     {
        audie.Paused();
     }
     else
     {
       audie.play();
     }
  }
```

Comment: oh thanks that seems to have done the trick .Is it possible for me to pause the current song ,and when i pause another image (pause image ) replaces the play ?

Comment: yes you can use `audie.pause()` method to pause the song similarly as you play that song using `audie.play()`

Comment: and how can i do it using the same button .For example the song is played when clicked and paused when clicked again.Thanks for all your help !!

Comment: Yes you can do it as well, for this you can check status of file like this `if(audio.paused==false){ audio.paused() }`

Comment: <img src="images/play.png" alt="Play Button width="37" height="30" onclick="Start('RWY.mp3')" onclick="Stop()"> i managed to pause the file but using a seperate function , is this how the markup should be to play and pause using the same button ?

Comment: you can do it using same markup, no need to make two different functions. I have updated my anwer

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working , your sure i have to keep the same html apart form the function name obviously

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid having many different functions for the same purpose. You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to make your code short and very simple.

```
$(document).ready(function() { // starting our code when document is loaded
    $('.playbtn').click(function() { // attaching this code to click event of any html element having _playbtn_ class
        $(this).data('song'); // getting song name from _data_ container of clicked element $(this)
        $('#myAudio').attr('src',songFileName).play(); // getting element myAudio bi its id, then setting it's src attribute and, finally, starting playback 
    });
});
```

and HTML for this will be following

```
<img src="images/play.png" class='playbtn' alt="Play Button" data-song="RWY.mp3" width="37" height="30" />
<img src="images/play.png" class='playbtn' alt="Play Button" data-song="EL.mp3" width="37" height="30" />
```

From now you need to add only *one* line to add new song button - just copy <img ... /> line, set new *data-song* value and... wuala!